# Why can't foursquare API consumers have multiple callback URLs?

Tags: foursquare

Is there a reason the Foursquare API v2 doesn't support multiple callback URLs for a consumer?   It's a big hindrance on dev ops to have to define a brand new application for every single test environment. AFAIK, no other major networks constrain app redirects to this extent.

Is there a rationale for this limitation? I get the risks of open redirects, and domain-only matches seems to be ruled out by the latest OAuth 2.0 draft spec, but multiple endpoints seem to be totally Kosher (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23#section-3.1.2.2).

Comment: I totally agree that this is a big pain when we're testing our apps. Foursquare folks, it would be great if we could get around this with multiple endpoints.

Comment: AFAIK even Saleforce follows a strict single callback per consumer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No real reason -- multiple callback URLs was added to the OAuth 2 spec relatively recently and support for it has not been added yet.